# How do I write a function to replace specific Markdown text?

Tags: markdown

At work, I mostly use Emacs for all my programming and text editing but I wouldn't really say I'm a pro. I'm more like beginner or intermediate so I'm not sure if this is really even a question.

I have been tasked with migrating our documentation from LaTeX to Markdown (Our own flavor of Markdown) and after converting to vanilla markdown with pandoc, I have found myself repeating the following pattern a lot.

Say I need to include an image in the `.md` file from the `figures/` directory. My markdown will look something like this

```
![Fission gas release experimental comparison of IFA-535 rod 809 during
the ramp test.](rod809_fgr){width="4in"}
```

And I need to convert it to this

```
!media figures/rod809_fgr.png 
    id=rod809_fgr 
    caption=Fission gas release experimental comparison of IFA-535 rod 809 during the ramp test. 
    style=width:50%
```

Notice how the file name in the parenths `(rod809_fgr)` became `figures/rod809_fgr.png` and `id=rod809_fgr` and the description was put into the caption. Also the text was indented a specific way.

How can I write a Lisp function that highlights the original markdown and gives me the output I want? Once again, not too familiar with Lisp and still a beginner with Emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regexp-based approach. Useful documentation links:

- [Defining interactive commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html#Defining-Commands).
- [Regular expression syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html#Syntax-of-Regexps), [regexp search](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html#Regexp-Search) and [match data](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Match-Data.html#Match-Data).
- [`save-excursion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Excursions.html#Excursions)

```el
(defun markdown-to-dylanjm-image ()
  "Convert a Markdown image element to dylanjm's house markup format."
  (interactive "@*")
  ;; Look for a Markdown image element before the cursor or immediately
  ;; after the cursor. Don't look any further than the start of the current
  ;; paragraph.
  (let ((limit (save-excursion
                 (backward-paragraph)
                 (point)))
        (regexp "\\s-*!\\[\\([^][]*\\)\\](\\([^()]*\\))\\({[^}{]*}\\)?"))
    (if (and (eq ?! (char-after (1- (point))))
             (eq ?\[ (char-after (point))))
        (backward-char))
    (while (not (looking-at regexp))
      (search-backward "![" limit))
    ;; If the search didn't error out, then we exited the loop with
    ;; `looking-at' matching `regexp'. The match data therefore contains
    ;; the parts of the image link.
    (skip-syntax-forward "-")
    (let ((caption (subst-char-in-string ?\n ?\  (match-string 1)))
          (id (match-string 2))
          (style (and (match-string 3)
                      (substring (match-string 3) 1 -1))))
      ;; Remove the Markdown syntax.
      (delete-region (- (match-beginning 1) 2) (match-end 0))
      ;; Add line breaks before and after if it looks like there aren't any.
      (unless (eolp)
        (open-line 1))
      (unless (<= (point) (save-excursion
                            (back-to-indentation)
                            (point)))
        (insert "\n"))
      ;; Insert the new syntax.
      (insert "!media figures/" id ".png\n"
              "    id=" id "\n"
              "    caption=" caption)
      (when style
        (insert "\n    style=" style)))))
```

To bind this command to a `C-c i` after loading the markdown-mode package, put this in your init file:

```el
(defun my-eval-after-load-markdown-mode ()
  (define-key markdown-mode-map "\C-ci" 'markdown-to-dylanjm-image))
(eval-after-load "markdown-mode" '(my-eval-after-load-markdown-mode))
```

Comment: Where do I run the 2nd part (to establish the key-binding)? I tried putting it in my init.el file but it's giving me warnings.

Comment: @dylanjm I had a misplaced parenthesis. Fixed.

Comment: hmmm I'm now getting a strange error after putting the code in my init.el file. `symbols value as variable is void: my-eval-after-load-markdown-mode`

Comment: I'd removed too many parentheses... Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, it's not really working for me. It turns off my markdown-mode when I copy/paste it into my init.el file

Comment: @dylanjm This answer must be cursed... Here, fixed and this time I tested it.

Comment: Thank you so much. That works perfectly and will speed up my workflow immensely.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your cursor at `"!"` (or anywhere before `"}"`) and run `adl/md-converting`, that should solve.

```
(defun adl/md-converting ()
  (interactive)
  (save-restriction
    (adl/md-remove-new-lines)
    (adl/md-bas ?\{ "style=width:50%")
    (adl/md-bas ?\[ "caption=")
    (adl/md-bas ?\( "id=")))

(defun adl/md-remove-new-lines ()
  (let ((beg (point)))
    (search-forward "}")
    (narrow-to-region beg (point)))
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (search-forward "\n" nil t) (replace-match " " nil t))
  (search-backward "!" nil t))

(defun adl/md-bas (delim tag)
  (search-forward (string delim))
  (let
      ((beg (point))
       (compl-delim
    (cond ((eq delim ?\() ?\))
          ((eq delim ?\[) ?\])
          ((eq delim ?\{) ?\}))))
    (search-forward (string compl-delim))
    (delete-char -1)
    (kill-region beg (point)))
  (delete-char -1)
  (end-of-line)
  (newline)
  (insert (concat "    " tag))
  (unless (eq delim ?{) (yank))
  (search-backward "!" nil t)
  (when (eq delim ?\()
    (forward-char)
    (insert "media figures/")
    (yank)
    (insert ".png")))
```

**EDIT:** 
You can map it to `C-x C-m` with `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-m") 'adl/md-converting)`. You should put these codes in your init file.

It is worth noting that `C-m` is `RET` so `C-x C-m` is equal to `C-x RET` (`C-x + ENTER`).

Comment: Wow! That's awesome! Is there a way to map it to keybindings like `C-x C-m` or something similar?

Comment: @dylanjm I updated the answer with the keybinding part.